# Disable swipe function in UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with two **ViewControllers** in it, one of them got a **NavigationController** connected so i can push to another **ViewController** using the **Push-Segue** embedded in a button. The **ViewController** that is being **pushed** have the `UIPageViewController` datasource enabled so i can swipe from the **pushed** *ViewController* back to the first **ViewController**.

I want to be able to disable the swip function in the **pushed** ViewController so i must press on the back button to return, not swipe.

I think that my `UIPageViewController` is not setting the correct view in the function **before** and **after**.

**Code for** `UIPageViewController`

```
class upAndDownViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {



var pages = [UIViewController]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page2")
    let topPage: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("topPage")



    pages.append(page2)
    pages.append(topPage)



    setViewControllers([page2], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)




}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {


    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
    let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)


    if (nextIndex < 1)
    {
        return nil
    }

    return pages[nextIndex]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!


    let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)


    if (previousIndex > 0)
    {
        return nil
    }



    return pages[previousIndex]


}
```

Comment: you ask for UIPageController or swipe back gesture of UINavigation?

Comment: I want UIPageController to disable itself when i press a button to go to another viewcontroller. i do not want to the swipe function to be enabled when entering a certain viewcontroller. @vienvu